# SQL Server CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert below formula into SQL Case Statement -

```
=If([Amount] Where( [Currency]="XYZ")=0 And [BucketCode]="111") Then   [Measure1]
  ElseIf([Amount] Where( [Currency]="XYZ") =0 And [BucketCode]="222") Then [Measure2]
 Else (Sum([Amount] )Where ([Currency]="XYZ"))
```

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Good for you, what is your actual problem?

Comment: What is the requirement. What do you want to return based on what conditions.

Comment: The issue I am facing is how to put where clause in Case statement. As you can see that in original expression there is where clause of curency attached with it. If I may have to rewrite this piece of code in Select statement, how do I put where clause so that It will affect only [Amount] and NOT [Measure1/2]. That is my question

Comment: @user2490024, you need to appreciate the fact that since this code is invalid (read: completely broken) SQL we have no way of knowing or even guessing your intentions. Additionally this code does not resemble any other language (at least the ones I know of). You need to provide some examples about the input data and desired output. For example your code appears to mix aggregates (`SUM`) with non-aggregate values in a single expression, which as a general rule cannot happen (there are exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than providing code to be translated you should provide problem statement. Please have a look at the code below it might be helpful.

```
CASE
WHEN 
    (CASE WHEN[Currency]="XYZ" THEN [Currency] END)=0 
    AND [BucketCode]="111" 
THEN [Measure1] 
WHEN 
    (CASE WHEN[Currency]="XYZ" THEN [Currency] END)=0 
    AND [BucketCode]="222" 
THEN [Measure2] 
ELSE Sum([Amount] for [Currency]="XYZ")
END
```

Comment: Sum([Amount] for [Currency]="XYZ") is giving error. I am on Sql server 2008 R2

Comment: You can do like.. 
`ELSE (CASE WHEN  [Currency]="XYZ" THEN Sum([Amount]) END)`
This is just for an Idea. You should explore it for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of the below query.

```
Select Col1 =
     CASE 
     WHEN  ([Amount]=0 And [BucketCode]="111") THEN 'Measure1'
     WHEN ([Amount]=0 And [BucketCode]="222") THEN 'Measure2'
     ELSE (SUM([Amount])) END 
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Currency]="XYZ"
GROUP BY [Currency],[BucketCode]
```